# Use abstract classes as function parameters

Tags: c#

I need help understanding the use of abstract classes. I have an abstract class called `WorldObject`:

```
public abstract class WorldObject
{
    public Vector3 position;
}
```

I have many classes that inherit from this, for example `Building` and `Tree`.

I want to create a method that loops through a `List` of `WorldObjects`, and return the closest one to me.
I want to be able to use this method with all my types of `WorldObjects`, but I can't get it to work:

```
public List<Building> buildings = new List<Building>();
public List<Tree> trees= new List<Tree>();

private void GoToClosestBuilding()
{
    var target = GetClosestWorldObject(buildings); //Error: Cannot convert building to WorldObject
}

Vector3 GetClosestWorldObject(List<WorldObject> objects)
{
    //...
}
```

When I try to pass my `Building` or `Tree` lists to my method, it returns an error that it cannot convert between `Building` and `WorldObject`, and so on.

How can I structure my code so that something like this would work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `List<Building>` is not assignment compatible to a `List<WorldObject>` because then you could do

```
List<WorldObject> worldObjects = buildings; // Not possible!
worldObjects.Add(tree); // Legal
```

`worldObjects.Add(tree);` is perfectly legal. But as `worldObjects` would reference a list of buildings, you would not be allowed to add it a tree!

However, you can change the signature of the method to

```
Vector3 GetClosestWorldObject(IEnumerable<WorldObject> objects)
{
    ...
}
```

Now, this works

```
var target = GetClosestWorldObject(buildings);
```

because the enumerable is declared as

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}
```

The `out` keyword states that `T` occurs only in out-positions, i.e. as return value or as out parameter. This makes the type co-variant.

See also:
- [Covariance and Contravariance (C#) - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic function.

```cs
Vector3 GetClosestWorldObject<T>(List<T> objects) where T: WorldObject 
{
    // ...
}
```

The problem, as mentioned by other answers, is that a `List<WorldObject>` is not the same as a `List<Building>`.  If you want to pass a `List` into your argument and not an `IEnumerable`, you can use a generic function that takes a `List` of `T` where `T` is a `WorldObject`.  Now that `T` is assigned to `Building`, `List<Building>` is acceptable.